# intent returns null on picture

Tags: android, android-intent

> ```
>          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1
>                 && null != data)
>             {               
>             Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
>             InputStream imageStream =getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
>             System.out.println("dfsdf");
>             Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
> ```

basically onactivityresult thats how i read, and i get selected image as null. when i selected my image from file manager ( /sdcard)..however when i selected from uhf player..i select from camera or screenshot, it works fine

> ```
>                Intent intent = new Intent();
>                 intent.setType("image/*");
>                 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
>                 startActivityForResult(
>                         Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
> ```

Comment: Examine the scheme of the `Uri` that you get back. Use a `ContentResolver` if the scheme is `content`.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); if i do that btw, it solves the problem.but user can never select image from sdcard ( file manager)

Comment: Well what becomes/is null exactly?

Comment: the uri selectimage = intent.getdata()   , select image is null

Comment: @user3278732 which phone you are using?

Answer (score 2):

```
//Here is some sample code to pick photo from gallery or get from camera.
```

//Declare the following

```
 private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 100;
     private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST=101;
```

//way to call startactivityforresult select photo from gallery(sd card)

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

//way to call startactivityforresult select photo from camera

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
         startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

//onActivityResult method

```
 @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  

                //pick image from gallery(sd card)  
                    if(requestCode==SELECT_PHOTO)
                    {

                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    InputStream imageStream = null;
                    try {
                        imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    imageView_Babypic.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                }
                    //pick image from camera
                    else if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                         Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data"); 
                         imageView_Babypic.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    }


                }

            }
```

//at last use this for camera use in your Manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: Why camera permission if you are taking images outside your app as an intent??

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to launch you intent chooser -

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent();
                pickIntent.setType("image/*");
                pickIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                String pickTitle = this
                        .getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.edit_general_select_or_take_picture); // Or
                                                                                    // get
                                                                                    // from
                // strings.xml
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent,
                        pickTitle);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                        new Intent[] { takePhotoIntent });

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent,
                        SELECT_PICTURE);
```

and your onActivityResult will be like this -

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        if (imageReturnedIntent != null) {
            if (imageReturnedIntent.getData() != null) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();



            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.